# How to overwrite a variable in a dynamic way and not in a hardcoded way?

Tags: javascript

I have something similar to this code:

```js
addBlock = document.querySelectorAll(`[slide='B.slide1'] .TEAM`);
addBlock = addBlock[addBlock.length - 1];
function addNewSimilarBlockOfCode(x) {
  HTML = x.outerHTML;
  //insert new block of code after the previous one:
  x.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', HTML);
  //redeclare x with the new added HTML code
  x = x; // here is the problem. this is an incorrect code!
  console.log('the new value of x is: ' + x);
}
addNewSimilarBlockOfCode(addBlock);
```

as you can see the problem is that the new x is still indicating the one in the argument which was the old value of x.
I need a dynamic way to implement this, I don't want to hardcode it, some people might say "instead of writing x = x, write instead:

```js
x = document.querySelectorAll(`${slide('B.slide1')} .TEAM`);
x = addBlock[x.length - 1];
```

The problem is I don't want to hardcode it.

The original code I have, it is currently working, but I want to change it from being a hardcoded function (the addField and the newField functions) to be dynamic so I can use them later:

```
 const UI = (() => {
    //TOOLS:
    const $ = (x) => document.querySelector(x);
    const $$ = (x) => {
      let element = document.querySelectorAll(x);
      element = slice_array(element);
      return element;
    };
    const slice_array = (x) => {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
    };
    const slide = (path) => {
      path = path.split(".");
      return `[scope='${path[0]}'][slide='${path[1]}']`;
    };
    //-------------</TOOLS>
    const addField = (element, replace) => {
      let HTML;
      console.log("replace this: " + replace[0] + " with this: " + replace[1]);
      HTML = element.outerHTML;
      if (replace instanceof Array)
        HTML = element.outerHTML.replace(replace[0], replace[1]);
      element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", HTML);
    };
    return {
      addField: addField,
    };
  })();

  const controller = ((UI, model) => {
    //TOOLS:
    const $ = (x) => document.querySelector(x);
    const $$ = (x) => {
      let element = document.querySelectorAll(x);
      element = slice_array(element);
      return element;
    };
    const slice_array = (x) => {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
    };
    const slide = (path) => {
      path = path.split(".");
      return `[scope='${path[0]}'][slide='${path[1]}']`;
    };
    //-------------</TOOLS>

    let addBlock;
    addBlock = $$(`${slide("B.slide1")} .TEAM`);
    const eventList = () => {
      addBlock[addBlock.length - 1].addEventListener("input", newField);
    };
    let newField = () => {
      let replaceThis, withThis;
      addBlock = $$(`${slide("B.slide1")} .TEAM`);
      replaceThis = `<span id="TEAM_NUMBER_${counter}">${counter}</span>`;
      withThis = `<span id="TEAM_NUMBER_${counter + 1}">${counter + 1}</span>`;
      replace = [replaceThis, withThis];
      addField(addBlock, replace);
    };
    let counter = 1;
    const addField = (addBlock, replace) => {
      e = window.event;
      const target = e.target || e.srcElement;
      //remove previous event listener
      addBlock[addBlock.length - 1].removeEventListener("input", newField);
      console.log(addBlock);
      //insert new field
      UI.addField(target.parentNode, replace);
      counter = counter + 1;
      //add new event listener
      addBlock = $$(`${slide("B.slide1")} .TEAM`);
      addBlock[addBlock.length - 1].addEventListener("input", newField);
    };
```

Comment: May I know why I'm getting a downVote? what's wrong with the question? I've said I have similar code to this and not this exact code.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. Consider to revise it. Keep it simple and neutral. Limit to the essential problem. If you do that, you might find a solution yourself. Anyway... The set of `x = x` is useless. Maybe you should return `x` to get the new one. But note that `x` is a reference. If you want a copy use `cloneNode`. If you return `x` it's not hardcoded anymore. (I haven't down voted. I also hate down votes without reasons. :) ).

Comment: if you write x=x this will mean that x is equal to the previous block of code and not the newly inserted one to the dom

Comment: I can paste the original code I'm working on here, but it will be a long code

Comment: But `x` (consider to rename to a more specific name) is an object, isn't? You use `x.outerHTML`. So I think this is a `HTMLElement` (or any [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)) So setting `x = x` does not change the value. It's the same reference. So you should use `cloneNode`. And maybe return it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) instead of getting `outerHtml` and `appending` it. And use `x.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clone);` & `x = clone;`.

Try it below.

```js
var addBlock = document.querySelectorAll(`.slide1 .TEAM`);
addBlock = addBlock[addBlock.length - 1];

function addNewSimilarBlockOfCode(x) {
  // pass true as parameter to copy with children nodes
  var clone = x.cloneNode(true);

  //insert new block of code after the previous one:
  // use insertAdjacentElement instead of insertAdjacentHTML
  x.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clone);

  //redeclare x with the new clone
  x = clone; // here is the problem. this is an incorrect code!
  console.log('the new value of x is: ' + x);
}
addNewSimilarBlockOfCode(addBlock);
```

```html
<div class='slide1'>
  <div class='TEAM'>
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be dynamic, that usually means **you want a function** to return a value for you.

You can try something like this:

```js
// Gets a live collection of HTML elements
const blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
printLength(blocks);

// Adds more elements and reports the new lengths
addNewBlock(blocks);
printLength(blocks);

addNewBlock(blocks);
printLength(blocks);


// Gets the block that is __currently__ the last one
function getLastBlock(blocks){
  const lastIndex = blocks.length - 1;
  const lastBlock = blocks[lastIndex];
  return lastBlock;
}

// Uses `getLastBlock` to determine where to add more content
function addNewBlock(blocks){
  let last = getLastBlock(blocks);
  last.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", last.outerHTML);
  
  last = getLastBlock(blocks); // Now, `last` is the new block
  last.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "I"); // To distinguish it from previous block
}

// Reports the current total number of blocks
function printLength(blocks){
  console.log(`blocks.length = ${blocks.length}`);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Block I</div>
```

NOTE: The `querySelectorAll` method returns a static list, so if you use it, you should call it inside your `getLastBlock` function so that it can retrieve the most recent version.